# DataBinding issue with knockout

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, data-binding, knockout.js, postback

When I am try to bind data using knockout when the pageload it work fine. But when postback it throws an error "You cannot apply bindings multiple times to the same element." and also data repeating wrong way.

Script and the view as in below. from the controller it returns the required viewmodel.

Plz help me to fix this issue..

SCRIPT:

```
> var dataCollection = ko.observableArray();
> 
> function loadShiftSummary() {
>     ko.cleanNode($("#shiftInfo"));
>     $.ajax({
>         url: 'testurl',
>         type: 'post',
>         contentType: 'application/json',
>         success: function (data) {           
>    
>             dataCollection = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.rosterViewModels);
>             ko.applyBindings(dataCollection, document.getElementById("shiftInfo"));
>         }
>     }); }
```

VIEW :

```
>  <tbody data-bind="foreach: dataCollection">
>         <tr>
>             <td data-bind="text: Description"></td>
>           
>             @for (int i= 0; date < 30; i++)
>             {
>                 <td data-bind="text: $data.CountArray()[@i]"></td>
>             }
>         </tr> 
> </tbody>
```

thanks

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this is, is that `ko.applyBindings(dataCollection, document.getElementById("shiftInfo"));` is called more than once.

What I would suggest is in your document ready put this

```
ko.applyBindings(dataCollection, document.getElementById("shiftInfo"));
```

and remove it from the function

```
function loadShiftSummary() {

    $.ajax({
        url: 'testurl',
        type: 'post',
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (data) {           

            dataCollection(ko.utils.unwrapObservable( ko.mapping.fromJS(data.rosterViewModels)));

        }
    }); 
}
```

`ko.applyBindings` should never be called more than once per page/section

Comment: this code dataCollection = ko.mapping.fromJS(data.rosterViewModels); should be dataCollection(ko.mapping.fromJS(data.rosterViewModels)) otherwise dataCollection will refer to new array and ui will refer to different array, so the data will not update in the ui.

Comment: @DhanaKrishnasamy yes you are correct, I missed that part, updating the code now, I also usually add `ko.utils.unwrapObservable` around that